# Split a column based on time range

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables with this kind of structure:

**Table 1:**

```
Datefrom    Dateto       DIM_code
20160101    20161231     dim_1
20170101    20191231     dim_2
```

**Table 2:**

```
Date        DIM_code
20160217    20
20170519    37
```

I need a table like this:

**Table - result:**

```
Date        dim_1    dim_2
20160217    20 
20170519             37
```

Comment: Yoda says: Pivot you are looking for, search the web you must.

Answer (score 0):

The use case is not clear. Can you please elaborate more on the problem statement?

By the looks of what you have explained, this should do the job for you.

```
SELECT t2.Date,
       (CASE WHEN t2.DIM_code=20 THEN t2.DIM_code END) AS dim_1,
       (CASE WHEN t2.DIM_code=37 THEN t2.DIM_code END) AS dim_2
FROM Table2 t2 JOIN
     Table1 t1 
WHERE t2.Date between t1.Datefrom AND t1.Dateto;
```

But I really doubt that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT t2.Date,
       (CASE WHEN t1.DIM_code = 'dim_1' THEN t2.DIM_code END) AS dim_1,
       (CASE WHEN t1.DIM_code = 'dim_2' THEN t2.DIM_code END) AS dim_2
FROM Table2 t2 JOIN
     Table1 t1 
WHERE t2.Date >= t1.Datefrom AND
      t2.Date <= t1.Dateto;
```